# "Nothing is compared with" or "Nothing is compared to"

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions

Do we say "Nothing is compared ***with*** the Egyptian pyramids" or "Nothing is compared ***to*** the Egyptian pyramids"?

If both are correct,is either one favourable in general or in British or American 
English?

Comment: The word "with" is the least of your problems. Neither sentence is correct. It should be "Nothing can be compared to ..." or "Nothing compares to..." The way you're phrasing it makes it sound like somebody is doing the comparing.

Answer (score 1):

Saying "Nothing is compared with the Egyptian pyramids" or "Nothing is compared to the Egyptian pyramids" implies that no one has ever done such a comparison.  Eg, no one has ever compared the height of a pyramid with the height of a well-known office building.  This is most certainly false.

Saying "Nothing *compares* with ...", on the other hand, implies that when a comparison is done, the pyramids are always found to be superior in some aspect.

Comment: Nothing is comparable to Egyptian Pyramids. Nothing can be compared to Egyptian Pyramids.  https://www.dailywritingtips.com/compared-to-or-compared-with/

Answer (score 0):

I made a grammatical change to the verb:

In regards to the use of **compare to** or **compare with**:

> - "Nothing compares **with** the Egyptian pyramids."

or

> - "Nothing compares **to** the Egyptian pyramids."

From the OED, either **with** or **to** is acceptable and my sense is both are used interchangeably with not much difference in AmE & BrE:

> to compare: (a thing) for one to compare, (a thing) to be compared,
>   comparable (**to, with**).

Comment: So does the same go for the original sentence?

Comment: yes, but the verb form is not grammatical.

Comment: I am sorry,but what do you mean?

Comment: "is compared' should be 'compares'  or 'compared' etc

Comment: Interestingly, I would take your two sentences slightly differently, even though the definitions are virtually identical! I would interpret the first sentence as suggesting that the pyramids are *unique*, while the second sentence suggests that the pyramids are *of superior quality.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be pernickety, then strictly speaking it should be "with" or nothing at all.

Why? Because the prefix "com" is Latin for "with" and the word "compare" comes from Latin.

> [compare](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=compare)  (v.) c. 1400,
> "regard or treat as equal;" early 15c. "liken, make a comparison,
> represent as similar," from Old French comparer "to compare, liken"
> (12c.), from Latin comparare "to liken, to compare," from com "with,
> together" (see com-) + par "equal" (see par (n.)).